# js/laravel-How to get exact id for user from element

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I need to find solution to get User id from users table with javascript or laravel. 
WHy i need it ?

Because i need to populate modal window popup with exact informations for users.
I have like 10 users , their ids and they are all shown now i need to get informations from database when someone click on that user and display his birth day, first name , last name,picture ....

here is my code where is our model window called index.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('includes')
    <link href="{{ url('org/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="{{ url('org/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {


            $('#chart-container').orgchart({
                'data': $('#ul-data'),
                'verticalDepth': 40,
                'depth': 20
            });
            $('.orgchart').addClass('noncollapsable');


            $('.title').on('click', function() {
                $('#exampleModalLong').modal();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .edge {
            display: block !important;
        }
</style>






@endsection


@section('content')




    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="header text-center">
            <h3 class="title">@lang('orgchart.title')</h3>
            <p class="category">@lang('orgchart.subtitle')</p>
        </div>



        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card" style="padding: 20px; overflow: auto;">
                <ul id="ul-data" style="display:none;">
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <li class="user-{{ $category->id }}">
                            {{ $category->getFullNameAttribute()}}
                            @if(count($category->childes))
                                @include('management.orgchart.manageChild',['childs' => $category->childes])
                            @endif
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                <div id="chart-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script>
        //$('#myModal').modal();

    </script>

    {{-- POPUP WINDOW ON CLICK --}}

   
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Popup Window title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    Using dummy content or fake information in the Web design process can result in products with unrealistic assumptions and potentially serious design flaws. A seemingly elegant design can quickly begin to bloat with unexpected content or break under the weight of actual activity. Fake data can ensure a nice looking layout but it doesn’t reflect what a living, breathing application must endure. Real data does.
                    Websites in professional use templating systems. Commercial publishing platforms and content management systems ensure that you can show different text, different data using the same template. When it's about controlling hundreds of articles, product pages for web shops, or user profiles in social networks, all of them potentially with different sizes, formats, rules for differing elements things can break, designs agreed upon can have unintended consequences and look much different than expected.

                    This is quite a problem to solve, but just doing without greeking text won't fix it. Using test items of real content and data in designs will help, but there's no guarantee that every oddity will be found and corrected. Do you want to be sure? Then a prototype or beta site with real content published from the real CMS is needed—but you’re not going that far until you go through an initial design cycle.

                    Lorem Ipsum actually is usefull in the design stage as it focuses our attention on places where the content is a dynamic block coming from the CMS (unlike static content elements that will always stay the same.) Blocks of Lorem Ipsum with a character count range provide a obvious reminder to check and re-check that the design and the content model match up.

                    Kyle Fiedler from the Design Informer feels that distracting copy is your fault:

                    If the copy becomes distracting in the design then you are doing something wrong or they are discussing copy changes. It might be a bit annoying but you could tell them that that discussion would be best suited for another time. At worst the discussion is at least working towards the final goal of your site where questions about lorem ipsum don’t.
                    Summing up, if the copy is diverting attention from the design it’s because it’s not up to task.

                    Typographers of yore didn't come up with the concept of dummy copy because people thought that content is inconsequential window dressing, only there to be used by designers who can’t be bothered to read. Lorem Ipsum is needed because words matter, a lot. Just fill up a page with draft copy about the client’s business and they will actually read it and comment on it. They will be drawn to it, fiercely. Do it the wrong way and draft copy can derail your design review.

                    Asking the client to pay no attention Lorem Ipsum isn't hard as it doesn’t make sense in the first place, that will limit any initial interest soon enough. Try telling a client to ignore draft copy however, and you're up to something you can't win. Whenever draft copy comes up in a meeting confused questions about it ensue.

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    {{--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>--}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


@endsection
```

And here is child class for the same orgchart

```html
<ul>
    @foreach($childs as $child)
        <li class="user-{{ $child->id }}">
            {{ $child->getFullNameAttribute()}}
            @if(count($child->childes))
                @include('management.orgchart.manageChild',['childs' => $child->childes])
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Uh...so, you can grab the class, do a string split, then parse the second item as an ID. But that's not really the best way. The whole setup is best rejigged - you shouldn't need to be grabbing random attributes from HTML elements and perform string manipulation on them to get the data needed. That's not scalable - next you might need the name or maybe even an address. What happens if you just need the city from the address? Having a user model client-side that you can refer to allows for way more flexibility.

Comment: Still, if you just need the ID and never anything else, then you can still improve this by having the ID as a custom `data-*` attribute. So you at least save on the "random" attribute you grab (it's very specific) and the string manipulation (it's the ID you want). But I really don't know if that suits your needs or you need to go in a different route.

Comment: I need script to display iformations based on id i want it in js or ajax if possible or even in laravel / php.. I don't have idea how to do it can you make some example for me just to get id when element is clicked and then i can display first name etc in popup window. I need to get id because every informations are diffrent for every user so i can not just pull out informations from database... :(

Comment: OK, I'll give an example with both grabbing the class and using a custom attribute. But I do urge you to think about scalability of the data needed in the future.

Comment: My firend told me to do something like this :  
Hi, so first of all you have to set the user id on the organigram Element.

Maybe with an onClick Element like „openUser(ID)“

And then you create an Funktion in JS
You can do it with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current setup, you put the ID as part of the class. So, you can get the class assigned to the HTML element and then split it to extract the ID

```js
$("ul li")
  .click(function(event) {
    //event.target is what you clicked on
    //you can wrap it in a jQuert element via $() to use jQuery features
    var $el = $(event.target); 
    
    var htmlClass = $el.attr("class");
    
    var id = htmlClass.split("-")[1];
    
    console.log("My ID is: ", id);
  });
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on a name:
<ul>
  <li class="user-1">Alice</li>
  <li class="user-2">Bob</li>
  <li class="user-3">Carol</li>
  <li class="user-4">David</li>
  <li class="user-5">Edel</li>
  <li class="user-6">Fred</li>
</ul>
```

However, this is error prone. If you have multiple classes, for example then this can be a problem. Let's say the classes are `user user-1 item`, then `split("-")` will give you `1 item`. If more classes have dashes, then it's even a bigger problem.

Instead, you can have your template generate [a custom `data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attribute. These are attributes you can put in the HTML that are designed to be anything you want them - you can choose what their name is (after the `data-` part) and what they store. So, if you change your template for generating the items, you can use `data-user-id="{{ $child->id }}"` and get HTML that looks like this:

```js
$(".user") //now we can use a common class, instead of having one per item
  .click(function(event) {
    var $el = $(event.target); 
    
    var id = $el.data("user-id");
    
    console.log("My ID is: ", id);
  });
```

```css
.user {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on a name:
<ul>
  <li class="user" data-user-id="1">Alice</li>
  <li class="user" data-user-id="2">Bob</li>
  <li class="user" data-user-id="3">Carol</li>
  <li class="user" data-user-id="4">David</li>
  <li class="user" data-user-id="5">Edel</li>
  <li class="user" data-user-id="6">Fred</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now when i edit your script for my example like this i am getting message into console My is id : undefined , i have into sql -> users->id table and i can not get it ..
   $('.title') //now we can use a common class, instead of having one per item
                .on('click', function(event) {
                    var $el = $(event.target);

                    var id = $el.data("id");

                    console.log("My ID is: ", id);
                });

            $('.title').on('click', function() {
                $('#exampleModalLong').modal();
            });
        });

Comment: We are using this script to display our organisation chart
https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart-Webcomponents